# Use JQuery Range Slider to Live-Update a CSS Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rangeslider

I'm trying to use individual range sliders to live-update the following CSS properties (specifically, minmax(20vw), grid-gap, and height):

```
#wrapper {
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vw, 1fr));
grid-gap: 20px;
}

#item {
height: 150px;
}
```

I'm using CSS grid and some 'VW values', so I'm not sure if I'm complicating things with these. I don't really know where to begin.

Live editable codepen:
https://codepen.io/db13/pen/ypdPOO

UPDATE:
Each individual range slider should update each property individually:
Slider 1: Grid Gap
Slider 2: Div width
Slider 3: Div Height

Comment: You can use `$("#wrapper").css("grd-template-columns", 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(' + 20 + 'vw, 1fr)')`

Comment: Is there something that must be done then with the the html?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different CSS property. Given sample below:

```
// gap update
$("#slider-grid").on('input change', function(e) {
    var minmax = this.value;
    $("#wrapper").css("grid-gap", minmax + 'px')
});

// height update
$("#slider-height").on('input change', function(e) {
    var minmax = this.value;
    $(".item").css("height", minmax + 'px')
});

// width update
$("#slider-width").on('input change', function(e) {
    var minmax = this.value;
    $("#wrapper").css("grid-template-columns", "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(" + minmax + "vw, 1fr))")
});
```

[CodePen Link - V2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqOebO)

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is so close! I think whats happening here is that all properties are being updated all at once by one slider. What if I wanted to separate each property out so that each range-slider updated one property only?

Comment: Ah this seems confusing to me. Could you update your question clearly?

Comment: I updated the original post, does this make it more clear?

Comment: Hey Ashok, thanks for your earlier comment, I updated the original post, does this make it more clear?
[Ashok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1530567/ashok-shah)

Comment: Updated Answer. I hope it helps for you.