# Use JQuery Range Slider to Live-Update a CSS Value (column / fr and column-gap)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to build a JQuiry range slider that live-updates my photo Grid columns and column-gaps. I have found a very similar post to this on which someone has commented that seemed like the solution but there is an error in his code. I unfortunately don’t have the knowledge to fix it so that’s why I am asking it here.

This is the post: [Use JQuery Range Slider to Live-Update a CSS Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444381/use-jquery-range-slider-to-live-update-a-css-value)

And this is his code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  
    $("#slider-grid").on('input change', function(e) {
        var minmax = this.value;
        $("#wrapper").css("grid-gap", minmax + 'px')
    });
  
    $("#slider-height").on('input change', function(e) {
        var minmax = this.value;
        $(".item").css("height", minmax + 'px')
    });
  
    $("#slider-width").on('input change', function(e) {
        var minmax = this.value;
        $("#wrapper").css("grid-template-columns", "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(" + minmax + "vw, 1fr))")
    });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: black;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vw, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin: 0vw;
  background: orange;
  border: 0px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="contrastSlider">
     <input id="slider-grid" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
  <input id="slider-height" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
  <input id="slider-width" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, I can’t comment on that post because I doin’t have enough reputation. That’s why I am kinda duplicating it. Hope that is not a problem.

Comment: Looks like all that is missing, in the codepen from the original question as well as here, is actually embedding the jQuery library.

Comment: @CBroe that indeed was missing :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Please read the [tour] and [ask]. Keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum, this is meant to be a collection of Q/As. I.e. please [edit] this according to [ask], to make one focused, clear, answerable question. No "update", no "Hi again" please.

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch for pointing that out. I deleted my comment which involved new questions.

Comment: Please remove all answering parts from the question and create a separate answering post to present your solution. Your solution does not belong into the question. It seems that this can be achieved by simply returning the question to its original version (which I did) and adding the answer post.

Comment: Okay @Yunnosch, thanks, I just posted the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding `jQuery` solved my question, as @CBroe proposed to do. I created a new snippet so you can see the Javascript in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#slider-grid").on('input change', function(e) {
    var minmax = this.value;
    $("#wrapper").css("grid-gap", minmax + 'px')
  });
  
  $("#slider-height").on('input change', function(e) {
    var minmax = this.value;
    $(".item").css("height", minmax + 'px')
  });
  
  $("#slider-width").on('input change', function(e) {
    var minmax = this.value;
    $("#wrapper").css("grid-template-columns", "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(" + minmax + "vw, 1fr))")
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: black;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vw, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin: 0vw;
  background: orange;
  border: 0px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<!-- Solution to question: importing jQuery from the link below: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contrastSlider">
     <input id="slider-grid" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
  <input id="slider-height" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
  <input id="slider-width" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there checked your solution its missing jQuery library. Also I modified code you will get more productive in this snippet. Also note dont use input + change here, no need of `change` event here its causing unwanted call to dom.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    const $grid = $('#slider-grid');
    const $height = $('#slider-height');
    const $width = $('#slider-width');
    $(document).on("input", {$grid, $height, $width}, function (e) {
        var curEl = e.target.id;
        if(curEl == $grid[0].id) {
            $("#wrapper").css("grid-gap", $grid.val() + 'px')
        }
        if(curEl == $height[0].id) {
            $(".item").css("height", $height.val() + 'px')
        }
        if(curEl == $width[0].id) {
            $(".item").css("width", $width.val() + 'px')
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
    background: black;
}

#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vw, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
    height: 150px;
    border: 0px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0vw;
    background: orange;
    border: 0px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contrastSlider">
    <input id="slider-grid" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
    <input id="slider-height" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
    <input id="slider-width" type="range" value="contrast" max="100" min="0" step="1"/>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```